# Laravel 4 - pass parameter in controller, through ajax to view

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

In my application, I call a function named checkProject, in my controller.  I do this via getJSON. I understand the use of append to display content from my response data, however I need to use the values to populate a javascript function within my blade view.

Is it possible to do this through sessions?  Is there another way I can pass this data through?

PROJECT CONTROLLER

```
public function getProject()
{ 
 $input = Input::get('option');
 $projects = Project::where('id', $input)->get();

 return Response::json($projects);
 // can session be set here?    
}
```

PROJECT.BLADE.PHP

This has getJSON which calls api/getproject which routes to the project controller function above.  Below is the Json call and the secondary JS function which needs to populate the values minTime and maxTime

```
$.getJSON("{{ url('api/getproject')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, 
 function(data) 
 {                    
 if (data.success != false ) { 
   $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       $('#open').append('<div>' + value.weekday_start_time +', ' + value.title +'</div>');
   });
 }
}); 

var logic = function( currentDateTime ){
        if( currentDateTime.getDay()==6 ){ 
           this.setOptions({
               minTime:'10:00',
               maxTime:'21:00'
           });
         } else 
             this.setOptions({
               minTime:'08:00',
               maxTime:'22:00'
           });
        };
 });
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question... What do you want to store in the session?

Comment: I want to pass the values of weekday_start_time to the bottom function 'logic'. So, in simple terms it graps from the api the value and somehow populates the minTime and MaxTime from these values.

Comment: Maybe call it like `logic(new Date(), value.weekday_start_time)` and change the function signature to `var logic = function(currentDateTime, weekdayStartTime){}`?